# Joining two columns (1 factor, 1 integer) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Below is the first 5 rows of my data: the data frame is called inverts

```
    Location Transect  Species         Count
    McAbee     M1       Bat Star         35
    McAbee     M1       Turban Snail     2
    McAbee     M1       Sun Star         1
    McAbee     M1       Chiton           1
    ..........
```

I am trying to join my species and count data together so I can perform an ANOVA to see the differences between location and transect. I have two locations and four transects total.

I believe the `tapply()` function is the correct one to use to join `Species` and `Count` together but I can't figure out the code.

I believe the code should be:

```
inverts$speciescount = tapply(inverts$Species, inverts$Count, ....)
```

So I have gotten some good feedback on how to combine the two columns, however, I am still unable to compare the data between transects and location. I am unsure on how to proceed.  What I want to do is create a code where it is:

```
Count ~ Transect
# or 
Count ~ Location
```

The problem with just doing that is the Count data is just a bunch of numbers and it is referenced to a species. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "join"?

Comment: I need them in a single column to run an ANOVA. I need the species and count to both be together because running the ANOVA with just count against location doesn't give me the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this either the character way:

```
within(inverts, speciesCount <- paste(Species, Count, sep=":")
```

or the factor way:

```
within(inverts, speciesCount <- Species:factor(Count))
```

Since this is in the context of linear modelling, the factor way seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, for d being your data.frame:

```
newd <- data.frame(d[,c("Location","Transect")],SpeciesCount=paste(d$Species,d$Count))
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for getting everything into one column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about what your inputs to a modeling function should be. If you are modeling counts, then something like this will be needed:

```
cfit <- glm(counts ~  transect + location + species, data=inverts, family="poisson")
anova(cfit)
```

If you wanted to look at the interaction of species with location, then you might examine this model:

```
cfit2 <- glm(counts ~  transect + location + species, data=inverts, family="poisson")
anova(cfit2)
```

It would be possible to do a linear regression, but then you may get nonsensical predictions like negative counts.